# I signed a member up while logged into civicrm (as they had no paypal account) Now their email and other details have taken over the original account?

Tags: issues

Can anyone assist with this at all? Unusual problem I think. I was accidentally logged into the account we use to mail members, and when signing up a new member his details inadvertedly had taken over our account details, I have changed the email back but it still shows as his name when sending out mailings. Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Have you also changed the name of the contact back to whatever it was before?

Comment: Drupal, WordPress? I ask and then the versions would be helpful - CiviCRM version as well as the codebase (e.g. WP, Drupal, etc.). For example, in WordPress there is a feature that assigns the permissions vis-a-vis WP or CiviCRM. It also deals with how the userbase is interpreted.

Comment: What member form did you use? Maybe the default contact to prefill the form is taken from the current authorized account. This is not unusual IMHO.